# jqPlot zoom highlight from left to right

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jqplot

I have a graph that displays date on X axis and some values on Y axis, what I would like to do is: when a user selects a "zoom area", the highlighter should auto-magically select from top to bottom of the graph, such that the user only focuses on selecting a slice from left to right.

How can I achieve such a thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ahhh, found it, it's

```
curosr -> constrainZoomTo: "x"
```

Comment: @Servant I can't yet... but you're welcome to use this as an answer and I'll plus and accept it.